# How many numbers $n\leq10000$ cannot be written as $x+\gamma x+\gamma\delta x$ with $n,x,\gamma,\delta \in \mathbf{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Given three positive integers $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z$ such that $y=\gamma \cdot x$ and $z=\gamma\cdot\delta\cdot x$ with $\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb{N}$, how many numbers $n\leq10000$ cannot be written as:
> $$n=x+y+z=x+\gamma\cdot x+\gamma\cdot\delta\cdot x$$

I started solving this problem, picking up some common terms. In fact, I can write:
$$n=x+\gamma\cdot x+\gamma\cdot\delta\cdot x=x\cdot(1+\gamma+\gamma\cdot\delta)=x\cdot \bigl(1+\gamma\cdot(\delta+1) \bigr)$$
But how can we go on?

Comment: if $x = \gamma = 1$, then $n = 2 + \delta$ so any $n \geq 3$ is possible

Comment: I may be misinterpreting your question, but are you suggesting "Someone else gives you $x,y,z$, and you get to choose $\gamma$ and $\delta$ in order to make natural numbers $n\leq 10000$".That is, $x,y,z$ are fixed but $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are free?

Comment: Taken literally, with $x,y,z$ **given** there is only one $n$ that can be written as $x+y+z$, hence there are $10000$ or $9999$ numbers that cannot

Answer (score 3):

Actually, every $n \geq 3$ can be written in this form, by simply taking $x = \gamma = 1$ and $\delta = n - 2$. If $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$, then $x(1 + \gamma(\delta + 1)) \geq 1 \cdot (1 + 1 \cdot (1 + 1)) = 3$ so $n = 1,2$ can't be written in this form.

If $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, then there is an even easier method by letting $\gamma = 0$ and $x = n$. Thus, every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written in this form then.

Answer (score 0):

> Given three positive integers $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z$ ...

I give \begin{align*} x &= 20\,000  \text{,}  \\ y &= 20\,000  \text{, and }  \\ z &= 20\,000  \text{.}  \end{align*}

> ... such that $y=\gamma \cdot x$ and $z=\gamma\cdot\delta\cdot x$ with $\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb{N}$, ...

Clearly, $\gamma = \delta = 1 \in \{0,1,\dots\} = \Bbb{N}$.  (See ISO 80000-2 for the membership of the set $\Bbb{N}$.)

> ... how many numbers $n\leq10000$ cannot be written as:
> $$n=x+y+z=x+\gamma\cdot x+\gamma\cdot\delta\cdot x$$

Since $x + y + z = 60\,000$, all (infinitely many) of the integers no greater than $10\,000$ cannot be so expressed.

In fact, even if an admissible triple of $x,y,z$ is chosen so that their sum is no greater than $10\,000$, infinitely many negative integers cannot be so expressed.